# Do UTM-tags in a backlink affect SEO

Tags: seo

Do UTM-tags (Urchin Traffic Monitor) in a backlink affect SEO?

E.g.

```
1) http://www.domain.tld/
2) http://www.domain.tld/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=rss
```

Both links are pointing from website A to the same webpage on website B (the one mentioned above), but look different. #2 isn't exactly a pretty URL.

I don't think it will be affecting SEO, but am not sure.

Can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

It *shouldn't* affect SEO as I would expect Google to recognize it's own product being used (Google Analytics). But to be on the safe side using canonical URLs to point to the non-query string version of the URL (http://www.domain.tld/) would be a smart idea.

Answer (score 0):

It will not affect SEO.

But bear in mind to use only one type of link on all the pages. Otherwise you will end up with duplicate content (both URLs pointing to the same final page).

Comment: So, when using canonical tags there won't be any problems, right?

Comment: There is no problem using canonical tags. The only thing is that it will not help you to much in SEO - but you will not be banned.

Comment: I edited my question as I believe there's some misunderstanding..